# BLE app sending data with time delay

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my BLE app,App discover the peripherals ,connect it and write some data successfully.Its taking too much time bcoz every time its connects ,discover for service and characteristics then `didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:` in this method it sends data

```
[discoveredPeripheral writeValue:payloadMessage forCharacteristic:maincharacteristics type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
```

....so i cannot send writevalue in `IBAction` so that it directely send data without invoking didconnect,discover for service and charcteristics.help me...

Comment: is there anyone to help me.. i need it urgently....plz

Comment: You need to show more code - please edit your question to include more detail.  Why can't you keep the connection once established?

Comment: didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService: code follows: if (error) { [self cleanup];return;}  for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) { [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
 maincharacteristics=characteristic;if(!payload ==nil ){ NSLog(@"%@", payload);NSData *payloadMessage = [payload dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];[discoveredPeripheral writeValue:payloadMessage forCharacteristic:maincharacteristics type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse]; lbl.text=@"Legroom Connected"; }else{ lbl.text=@"Bluetooth Connected"; } }

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code there

Comment: @paulw11 what m missing in above code,plz help me

Comment: In the `for` loop you should verify if the `characteristic` object has the `UUID` that you're looking for. Also if you got the right service. A BLE device can have more than one service, each service can have more characteristics.

Comment: how to deal with characteristic object ,can u explain with code

Answer (score 0):

If you are already connected to the device (verify `isConnected` value of the peripheral) then you don't have to run the discovery of services and characteristics again. If it's a new connection, then you have to do the discovery, there is no other way on iOS. In my experience the discovery is quite fast, I don't think it should slow down your app. For a better experience, display an activity view while the discovery and writing are running.

Comment: thanks,But whenever i write this [discoveredPeripheral writeValue:payloadMessage forCharacteristic:maincharacteristics type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];in IBAction data is not sending.I think do i make any changes in maincharacteristics?my code is below:  --

Comment: Could you issue the write with `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse` so you could monitor the actions? Have you implemented `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:` to check for errors? Your code was not included, you could use a pastebin service for that and post the link.

Comment: yah,i included peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:,it invokes but no errors,only data will not pass to peripheral..